# how to get the Selected item in dropdownlist while click the Edit button in inline kendo grid in asp

Tags: javascript, asp.net, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

***How to Display the Selected Item from Database in Kendo Grid while click the Edit Button*
**My Coding Like****

`var grid= $("#DivUser").kendoGrid(` 
          `{` 
             `dataSource: DataSource4,`
                `scrollable: true,`
               `sortable: true,`
                `filterable: false,`
              `reorderable: true,`
                 `resizable: true,`
              `pageable: true,`
               `toolbar: [ { text : "Add new record", name: "popup",`
`iconClass: "k-icon k-add"} ],`
          `editable  : {`
                  `mode : "inline"`
 `columns:    [`

```
                {
                    field: "LoginName",
                    title: "Login Name",
                    width:"175px"
                },


                     {
                    field: "ScopeId",
                    title: "Scope Id",
                    editor: ScopeDropDownEditor
},
```

`{`
                       `command: ["edit", "destroy"],`
                        `title: "&nbsp;",`
                        `width: "175px"`
                   `}`
               `]`
         `}).data("kendoGrid");`

`var DataSourceScope = new kendo.data.DataSource(`
           `{`
 transport: 
 {
 read: 
 {
 url: "WebServices/Project.asmx/GetScope",
 data: "{}",
contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
type: 'POST',
  dataType: 'json'
  },
 parameterMap: function(options, operation) 
{
 if (operation == 'read')
          return kendo.stringify(options);
}
 },
 schema: 
{
 data: function(Data) 
 { 
  return (Data.d); 
  },
  model: 
{
id: "ScopeId",
  fields: 
  {
   ScopeId: { type: "number"},
ScopeName: { type: "string"}
 }
}
},
 error: function(e) 
{`<br>`
var xhr = e[0];
var statusCode = e[1];
var  errorThrown = e[2];
 alert('DataSourceScope - ' + xhr + ', ' + statusCode + ', ' + errorThrown);
  }`<br>`
  });
 function ScopeDropDownEditor(container, options) 
{
$('
data-bind="value:' + options.field + '"/>')
.appendTo(container)
 .kendoDropDownList(
  {
 autoBind: false,
 dataSource: DataSourceScope
  });
 }       `

in my webservice code like

```
 public class Scopes
  {
      int _ScopeId;
      string _ScopeName;

      public int ScopeId
      {
          get { return _ScopeId; }
          set { _ScopeId = value; }
      }

      public string ScopeName
      {
          get { return _ScopeName; }
          set { _ScopeName = value; }
      }

      public Scopes() { }

      public Scopes(int ScopeId, string ScopeName) { this.ScopeId = ScopeId; this.ScopeName = ScopeName; }



}

  [WebMethod]
  public List<Scopes> GetScope()
  {

      string StrConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["sample"].ConnectionString;
      SqlConnection SqlConnection1 = new SqlConnection(StrConnectionString);
      SqlCommand SqlCommand1 = new SqlCommand("select distinct ScopeId,(select ScopeName from Scope2 where Scope2.ScopeID=User2.ScopeId)as ScopeName from User2", SqlConnection1);

      DataTable DataTable1 = new DataTable();
      SqlDataAdapter SqlDataAdapter1 = new SqlDataAdapter(SqlCommand1);
      SqlDataAdapter1.Fill(DataTable1);

      List<Scopes> ListScope = new List<Scopes>();
      foreach (DataRow DataRow1 in DataTable1.Rows)
      {
          ListScope.Add(new Scopes(Convert.ToInt32(DataRow1["ScopeId"]), Convert.ToString(DataRow1["ScopeName"])));
      }

      return ListScope;

  }
```

this is Ok..
But after Click Edit button the dropdownlist items like 1st item 
for Example

ScopeName id dropdownlist 
items Admin, Developer,tester

in database james is tester
if i click Edit Button Means

`Name                ScopeName` 
`James               admin`
                   `developer`
                   `tester`

How to Bind and How i displya the SElected items?
thankx in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

edited

fetch data directly using java script

```
 var xhReq = new XMLHttpRequest();
 xhReq.open("POST", 'WebServices/Project.asmx/GetScope', false);
 xhReq.send(null);
 var DataSourceScope = JSON.parse(xhReq.responseText);

 function ScopeDropDownEditor(container, options) 
    {
    $('<input name="' + options.field + '"/>').appendTo(container).kendoDropDownList({
                            dataTextField: "ScopeName",
                            dataValueField: "ScopeId",
                            dataSource: DataSourceScope.d

                        });
    }
```

Comment: its not coming :(   i used that Above Codings Only... webservice return the Scope id and Scope Name like 1 admin , 2 Developer , 3 tester

Comment: check your DataSourceScope is it having value in format [{ScopeId:'',ScopeName:''},{..},..]

Comment: are you using custom template for popup??

Comment: I cant understand Can you give me a solution,, am using inline editing for edit function.